# Validation and compare inputs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with inputs.  I want to compare each row and show a message.  For messages we can use Bootstrap:

```
foreach..

<td>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $real_price ?>" id="real_price">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" id="price">
</td>

..endforeach
```

I want to compare this values with jQuery.

For example:
 `if price < real_price - i` have a popover message "You can't set price smaller then real price".  Maybe a good idea is to use onchange event?

Comment: ID of an element must be ***unique***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden fields are useless, use data attributes in your input field to store real price like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="10" data-realprice="11">
            <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="12" data-realprice="13">
            <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below the jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.val() < that.data('realprice')) {
            that.next('span').html('You cant set price smaller then real price');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var real_price = $("#real_price").val();
     var price = $("#price").val();
     $('#btn').live("click",function(){
        if(real_price < price){
           alert("You cant set price smaller then real price");
           return false;
        }
        else{
           return true;
       }
    });
});
```

Try this